# Apache match {HTTP_HOST} in {HTTP_COOKIE}

Tags: apache, variables, mod-rewrite

I want to check if {HTTP_HOST} is in {HTTP_COOKIE} and if not redirect to one cookie value.

The cookie is correctly set with : (cookie name is DST_HOST)

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !DST_HOST [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ - [CO=DST_HOST:%{HTTP_HOST}:mydom.x]
```

Now I'm struggling with the RewriteCond statement as we cannot compare two variables.

I can easily test if the cookie is set with :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} DST_HOST
```

But I cannot do the variable comparaison test. The idea would be something like :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !DST_HOST=%{HTTP_HOST}
```

The right portion of the statement isn't evaluated we can only put static contents here.

I then tried with something found in Apache configuration guide :

```
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_COOKIE} -strmatch '*%{HTTP_HOST}*'"
```

But it doesn't evaluate the variables (I'm running Apache 2.4, maybe this only works with Apache 2.5)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Jean-Damien

Comment: You can use Apache If statements I believe. Btw,  Apache 2.5 doesn't exist

Comment: Found it here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!!%{HTTP_COOKIE} !^(.+)!!(.*)\1(.*)$
```

Wildcard must be used as {HTTP_COOKIE} can contains many cookies.